# Vectorization of Comparisons and Column Selection for Performance

Tags: python, pandas, performance, vectorization

I am trying to vectorize a loop that replaces values in a dataframe (df) based on values in another dataframe (df_override). For each row in df_override, we find the "name" column match in df and replace its "Field" column to a new value specified in "New Value". There's an if statement that matches on a different column if name is an integer.

I have two loops written out that does this. However the aim is to improve performance as much as possible. The old one is slower as it uses iterrows so I moved on to a np loop. I am hoping to vectorize this loop to further improve run time but I can't think how to proceed.

Old Loop (slow)

```
for index, row in df_override.iterrows():
    if(not str(row["name"]).isdigit()):
        df.loc[df["name"] == row["name"], row["Field"]] = row["New Value"]
    else:
        df.loc[df["id"] == row["name"], row["Field"]] = row["New Value"]
```

New Loop (faster)

```
fields = df_override["Field"].values
names = df_override["name"].values
values = df_override["New Value"].values

for field, name, value in zip(fields, names, values):
    if not str(name).isdigit():
        df[field] = np.where(df["name"]  == name, df[field], value)
    else:
        df[field] = np.where(df["id"]  == name, df[field], value)
```

Doesn't Work (due to the comparison, and the fields selection doesn't seem to work as intended)

```
fields = df_override["Field"].values
names = df_override["name"].values
values = df_override["New Value"].values

#Trying without the if statement here
df[fields] = np.where(df["name"]  == names, df[fields], values)
```

Sample Data

```
df_override
"name"  "Field"  "New Value"
apple    color     red
100     is_number  True

df
"name" "id" "color"  "is_number"
apple   300   blue      False
apple   200   yellow    False
banana  100   green     False

df (after processing)
"name" "id" "color"  "is_number"
apple  300    red       False
apple  200    red       False
banana 100    green     True
```

Comment: can their also be a color in the name column of df_override?